# Double space ENTIRE document in latex

Tags: latex, space, caption

In latex, I want to double space the entire document, including the footnote and the table caption.

I have tried

\usepackage{setspace}

\doublespacing

It works for the main text, but does not work on the table caption.

Does anyone have any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) detects the presence of [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) and allows you to set the `font` key-value accordingly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace,caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\captionsetup{font=doublespacing}% Double-spaced float captions

\doublespacing% Double-spaced document text

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption[lipsum2]{\lipsum[2]}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Werner, that's what I want!